# Is it safe to re-use the same p and q to generate a new pair of keys in RSA if the old private key was compromised?

Tags: rsa, public-key

Say I selected two large primes `p` and `q` for RSA and computed my public key `(e, n=pq)` and my private key `(d)`.

Now, I was careless and compromised my private key `(d)`. `p` and `q` were not leaked. Taking into account that `(e, n)` were already public knowledge, would it be safe to generate a new key pair with the same `p` and `q` or are they somehow compromised by the leaking of the private key?

If it would not be safe, how could someone compute `p` and `q` from my public-private key pair?

Comment: In practice almost everything in this century uses PKCS1 privatekey format which stores p,q explicitly as well as d-mod-pm1, d-mod-qm1, qinv-mod-p for CRT, so they're already compromised. But that's an answer for security.SX not crypto.SX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not safe.

There are several methods to compute $p$ and $q$ from $n$, $e$ and $d$. See appendix C of [this document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Br2.pdf#page=121).

Comment: Very useful link, thanks! For completeness I would quote the two mentioned methods in the answer, in case the link dies at any point in the future.